# Please help identify the mistake in this clock divider code

Tags: verilog

Clock divider from 50mhz (verilog code). I am trying to burn this on fpga but its not working properly. I am using model sim from mentor graphics. Please help identify my mistake.

```
module clk_div(
clk,
rst,
count);

parameter count_width=27;
parameter count_max=25000000;

output [count_width-1:0] count;
reg [count_width-1:0] count;
input clk,rst;

initial
count=0;

always@(posedge clk)
  if (rst)
  begin
      count<=0;
  end
  else if (count<count_max-1)
  begin
      count<=count+1;
  end
  else if (count==count_max)
  begin
      count <=~count;
  end
  else if (count>count_max)
  begin
      count<=0;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [verilog code for the design clock divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890725/verilog-code-for-the-design-clock-divider)

Comment: Based on the time stamp this is the original, making [verilog code for the design clock divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890725/verilog-code-for-the-design-clock-divider) the duplicate. Based on the comment in other question, both questions appears to be "Do My Homework"

Comment: I don't think you need that many bits to count to 25M: ceiling[log2(25000000)] = 25.

Answer (score 0):

Three things. First, you need `begin` and `end` for your `always` block. Second, why are you doing `count <= ~count` when the count hits the max? Shouldn't you just set it back to 0? Third, you can't give the internal `count` register the same name as the `count` output. You will need to call one of them something else. Actually, why do you want to output `count`? If this is a clock divider, you want to output another clock, right? The following should work.

```
module clk_div(
    clk,
    rst,
    outclk);

parameter count_width=27;
parameter count_max=25000000;

reg [count_width-1:0] count;
input clk,rst;
output outclk;
reg intern_clk;
assign outclk = intern_clk;


initial begin
    count=0;
    intern_clk=1'b0;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst)
        count <= 0;
    else if (count == count_max) begin
        count <= 0;
        intern_clk <= !intern_clk;
    end else
        count <= count + 1'b1;
end

endmodule
```

But it seems like you are trying to divide the clock down to 1 Hz. That's quite a lot. I recommend you use a PLL instead of making your own clock divider. Since you mention a 50 MHz clock, I'm guessing you are using an Altera FPGA? If so, open up the MegaWizard plugin manager and create a PLL.

Comment: thank you for the help .But i just compiled your verilog code and it is not working.Error message="illegal reference to net outclk in line 12"

Comment: Bleargh, this is what happens when you try to write Verilog without access to a verilog compiler. I've edited it, try it now.

Comment: thanks . It compiled successfully.It's looking like it will work.I will burn it on fpga and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: `begin`-`end` around the `always` block is not required but recommended. Your third point is invalid because `count` as `output` and `reg` is legal IEEE 1364-1995 syntax. IEEE 1364-2001 introduced allowing the definition in one line, ie `output reg [count_width-1:0] count;`. However, I agree that `count` should not be an output of a clock divider. I'm guessing @john_conner is trying to debug from fpga and not a simulator, hence `count` is an output.

Comment: Huh, I knew about `output reg var;`, but I didn't know that it was an alias for `output var; reg var;`. Thanks Greg!

Comment: @ZhehaoMao- please check this one also.i wrote another one for clock divider...                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890725/verilog-code-for-the-design-clock-divider